# Debug error R6010 - abort() has been called

Tags: c++, boost, filesystems

I am trting to make a program which outputs the names of all files in the folder in which it is located and if two of them have the same size, it only outputs one. Please note that I'm new to the boost library and not an experienced programmer.

Here is what I have come up with:

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>      
#include <iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstdio>
using namespace std;
void files(string a = ".")
{
bool check = 1;
boost::filesystem::directory_iterator iterator(a);

for (; iterator != boost::filesystem::directory_iterator(); ++iterator)
{

    if (is_directory(iterator->path()))
    {
        files(iterator->path().string());
    }
    else
    {
        boost::filesystem::directory_iterator iterator2(a);
        iterator2 = iterator;
        if (iterator != boost::filesystem::directory_iterator())
        {
            iterator2++;
        }
        for (; iterator2 != boost::filesystem::directory_iterator(); ++iterator2)
        {
            if (file_size(iterator->path()) == file_size(iterator2->path()))
            {
                check = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    if (check == 1)
    {

        cout << (iterator->path().filename()) << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        check = 1;
    }
}
}


int main()
{
files();
}
```

I tried to make it list all files without exceptions and it worked fine but when I add the second for loop and the second directory_iterator something goes wrong.

Comment: What does get wrong for the second loop? [ask]

Comment: Do you only want to output the first file found that has the same size as another file?  If so, then you could easily have done this using a `std::map<unsigned long, long, std::string>` without all the loops.

Answer (score 0):

The underlying problem is that `boost::filesystem::directory_iterator` is an input iterator that makes no guarantees about preserving equality: see the note at the [directory_iterator documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/filesystem/doc/reference.html#Class-directory_iterator).

In the implementation, it may well be using something like the POSIX `opendir`, `readdir` interface, where there is one underlying open file descriptor from which directory entries are being successively read.

Consequently, advancing `iterator2`, which may share the same underlying state as `iterator1` after the assignment, may well be changing what `iterator1` will return as well.

Indeed, on my test platform (Linux, g++), after the `iterator2` loop completes, and iterator2 is equal to the end iterator, `iterator1` is also equal to the end iterator, and the program segfaults when it tries to access the filename.

In short, iterator2 and iterator1 do not have independent state, even though it is not obvious that that should be the case. To work around this issue, it's easiest to keep a record of the file sizes you have seen in a `std::set` (or `std::unordered_set` in C++11), and only print the path if the set does not yet contain that file size.

I've included here a version which uses `std::set` to do this. To keep things simple, I've left out the recursive descent into sub-directories. You'll need to decide if you want to omit files which have the same size as a file in the same sub-directory, or as a file in any sub-directory.

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>      
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

using namespace std;
void files(string a = ".")
{
    boost::filesystem::directory_iterator iterator(a),dir_end;
    std::set<uintmax_t> file_sizes;

    for (; iterator != dir_end; ++iterator) {
        bool emit = true;

        if (!is_directory(iterator->path())) {
            uintmax_t size = file_size(iterator->path());
            if (file_sizes.find(size) == file_sizes.end()) {
                // set does not contain this file size yet.
                file_sizes.insert(size);
            }
            else {
                // set already contains this file size, so don't print path
                emit = false;
            }
        }

        if (emit) {
            cout << (iterator->path().filename()) << endl;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    files();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made this as a finger exercise myself.

I realize it's probably far too generic/complicated for your purpose (e.g. it gracefully handles the cases where getting the file size fails due to e.g. permission issues), but perhaps you would still be able to get some inspiration from it:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea0b2294ce22e422)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/range/adaptors.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

template <
    typename KeyFunc,
    typename OutputUnique,
    typename HandleDupe,
    typename Path = boost::filesystem::path,
    typename KeyType = decltype(std::declval<KeyFunc>()(Path{})),
    typename Record = std::pair<boost::optional<KeyType> const, Path>
>
void files(std::string const& curdir, OutputUnique output, KeyFunc const& key, HandleDupe const& handler)
{
    using namespace boost::adaptors;
    using namespace boost;

    using path  = fs::path;
    using paths = std::vector<path>;

    auto safe_key = [&key](path const& p) { 
        optional<KeyType> sz;
        try { sz = key(p); } catch(...) { }
        return std::make_pair(sz, p); 
    };

    std::function<void(path const&)> recurse = [&](path const& curdir) {
        paths files;
        paths dirs;

        std::map<optional<KeyType>, path> seen;

        try {
            auto entries 
                = make_iterator_range(fs::directory_iterator(curdir), {})
                | transformed(std::mem_fn(&fs::directory_entry::path))
                ;

            std::partition_copy(
                    entries.begin(), entries.end(),
                    back_inserter(dirs),
                    back_inserter(files),
                    [](path const& p) { return is_directory(p); }
                );

            for(auto& f: files) {
                auto insertion = seen.insert(safe_key(f));

                if (!insertion.second && insertion.first->first)
                    handler(*insertion.first, safe_key(f));
                else
                    *output++ = f;
            }

            boost::for_each(dirs, recurse);
        } catch(std::exception const& e) {
            std::cerr << "Skipping " << curdir << ": " << e.what() << "\n";
        }
    };

    recurse(curdir);
}

template <typename OutputUnique = std::ostream_iterator<fs::path> >
void files(std::string const& curdir = ".", OutputUnique output = std::ostream_iterator<fs::path>(std::cout, "\n"))
{
    using fs::path;
    using Record = std::pair<boost::optional<size_t> const, path>;
    files(
            curdir,
            output, 
            [](path const&p) { return file_size(p); },
            [](Record const&, Record const&) { }
         );
}

#include <boost/function_output_iterator.hpp>

int main() { 
    files("."); // prints non-dupes recursively

    // advanced use: print nothing for non-dupes, but print the duplicate pairs
    auto devnull = boost::make_function_output_iterator([](fs::path){});
    files(".", 
            devnull,                                     // back_inserter(some_vector), etc.
            [](fs::path const& p){return file_size(p);}, // some other key? 
            [](auto const& dupe, auto const& orig) {
                std::cout << "Duplicate size (" << *dupe.first << ") in " << dupe.second << "\n"
                          << "\tOriginal: " << orig.second << "\n";
            }); 
}
```

Prints

```
"./main.cpp"
"./a.out"
Duplicate size (3208) in "./main.cpp"
    Original: "./dupe.cpp"
```